# Function Null for variant in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, null, delphi-2010, variant

Where is this function in Delphi 2010?

```
function Null: Variant;
begin
  _VarNull(TVarData(Result));
end;
```

in Delphi 6 it was in Variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In D2010 it's still in Variants, looking exactly as you described.  It's defined on line 112 of Variants.pas.

Comment: What did you do over the last couple weeks? :P

Comment: Perhaps, it's time for me to start coffee